# GEM command not found after installing ruby-1.9.3 from source in linux redhat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I tried installing ruby from source ruby-1.9.3-p0.tar.gz

these are the steps followed 
wget http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.3-p0.tar.gz
tar xzvf ruby-1.9.3-p0.tar.gz

cd ruby-1.9.3-p0 $ ./configure --prefix=/scratch/$user/RUBY  --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-opt-dir=/scratch/$user/RUBY/lib 
$ make 
$ make install

Installation went fine , but when i run gem install bundler , it says 
gem command not found

how do i find my gem PATH where it is installed or where is my gem installed?

Does this ruby version have gem ? please find this link https://gist.github.com/deone/7527595 
, which can be used for running gem install bundler

Please suggest  a solution

Comment: have you tried using or even searching rvm ?

Comment: Is your Ruby working? Try in console `ruby --version`

Comment: Did you use `sudo gem install`?

Comment: HI @caffeine,@Antek,@Thiago , i dont have rvm installed , Please find my system details

Comment: [user@host ~]$ which ruby  
~/bin/ruby  
[user@host ~]$ ruby --version  
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]
[user@host ~]$ /usr/local/packages/aime/ias/run_as_root bash
[root@host ~]# gem install
bash: gem: command not found

Comment: [user@host ~]$ rvm --version
-bash: rvm: command not found
[user@host ~]$ echo $PATH
/scratch/user/bin:/scratch/user/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/dev_infra/platform/bin:/usr/dev_infra/generic/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/ade/bin

Comment: [user@host ~]$
[user@host ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 (Tikanga)

This is where my ruby exist ,
[user@host ruby]$ ls
1.9.1  gems  site_ruby  vendor_ruby
[user@host ruby]$ pwd
/scratch/user/RUBY/lib/ruby
[user@host ruby]$ ls
1.9.1  gems  site_ruby  vendor_ruby

Comment: Couldn't make out what gem PATH i need to add in env $PATH before executing gem install bundler

Comment: You are using 2 different ruby versions and probably the path isn't getting set rightly . I would suggest you to move forward by installing RVM as it allows you to maintain different ruby versions for each project .

Comment: Thanks @Caffeine , But i have only one ruby installed ,  i removed the default version of ruby .

Comment: @Caffeine , can i add this path to my env $PATH ie  export PATH=scratch/user/RUBY/lib/ruby/gems:$PATH ?

Comment: @Caffeine ; i have these two files under gems=> rake-0.9.2.2 rdoc-3.9.4

Comment: do i need to add ~/.gemrc before installing ruby?